# change names of files consistently

Tags: rename

I have a folder with folder names looks like:

```
enum_1              enum_118  enum_140  enum_16   enum_178  enum_209  enum_227  enum_246  enum_27   enum_45  enum_63  enum_88
enum_10             enum_119  enum_141  enum_160  enum_179  enum_21   enum_228  enum_247  enum_28   enum_46  enum_64  enum_9
enum_100            enum_12   enum_142  enum_161  enum_18   enum_210  enum_229  enum_248  enum_29   enum_47  enum_65  enum_90
enum_102            enum_120  enum_143  enum_162  enum_180  enum_211  enum_23   enum_249  enum_3    enum_48  enum_66  enum_91
enum_103            enum_121  enum_144  enum_163  enum_181  enum_212  enum_230  enum_25   enum_30   enum_49  enum_67  enum_92
enum_104            enum_122  enum_145  enum_164  enum_182  enum_213  enum_231  enum_250  enum_31   enum_5   enum_68  enum_93
enum_105            enum_123  enum_146  enum_165  enum_183  enum_214  enum_232  enum_251  enum_32   enum_50  enum_69  enum_94
enum_106            enum_124  enum_147  enum_166  enum_184  enum_215  enum_233  enum_252  enum_33   enum_51  enum_7   enum_95
enum_107            enum_125  enum_149  enum_167  enum_185  enum_216  enum_234  enum_253  enum_34   enum_52  enum_70  enum_96
enum_108            enum_126  enum_15   enum_168  enum_186  enum_217  enum_235  enum_254  enum_35   enum_53  enum_71  enum_98
enum_109            enum_127  enum_150  enum_169  enum_187  enum_218  enum_236  enum_255  enum_36   enum_54  enum_72  enum_99
```

I would like to rename all of them so that, they look like

```
enum_00001 enum_00118 ...
```

How should I achieve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `printf` to format the numerical part of the name properly in a loop:

```
for name in enum_*; do
    mv -i -- "$name" "$( printf 'enum_%05d' "${name#*_}" )"
done
```

The `${name#*_}` will expand to the numerical part of the original name, i.e. `73` for `enum_73` (it removes everything up to and including the first `_` in the name).  The `enum_%05d` formatting string will format this integer so that it becomes a zero-filled five-digit number prefixed by `enum_`, i.e. `enum_00073`.

Answer (score 5):

With Perl `rename`:

```
prename 's/(\d+)/sprintf "%05d", $1/e' enum_*
```

Answer (score 1):

Another **bash** variation:

```
#!/bin/bash
for fname in enum_*
do
    IFS=_ read n d <<< $fname   # splitting file name by separator `_`
    mv "$fname" "$(printf '%s_%05d' $n $d)"
done
```